# Integrate a rational function with a denominator in the form a - cos(x)

Tags: calculus

I am preparing for a basic level calculus test and came across this problem:

$$ \int_0^{\pi/2} \dfrac{1}{2-\cos{x}} dx$$

Which appears to be simple enough before I realize that I can't multiply the top and bottom by $ 2+\cos{x} $ and get anywhere fast.  The prompt and Wolfram Alpha suggest a u-substitution of $ u = \tan{\frac{x}{2}} $ but I really have no idea how to implement that.  How is this substitution used?  Is this even an appropriate problem for my current level of math knowledge?

Comment: The $u=\tan \frac x2$ substitution is also called the _Weirstrass substitution_; it's widely-used because all of the trigonometric functions of $x$ are rational functions of $\tan \frac x2$.  See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tangent_half-angle_substitution for more details.

Comment: Ok I'm pretty sure we have definitely not covered that so far in my class so I'm going to stop worrying about not having known what it was.  Thanks for the link - that really answered my question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

hint: use the sub $u = \tan( x/2), \cos t = \frac{1-u^2}{1+u^2}$ and some partial fraction.

differencing you get $$du = (1 + u^2) dx/2,  x = 0 \to u = 0, x = \pi/2\to u = 1$$ therefore the $\int_0^{\pi/2} \frac{dx}{2-\cos x}$ is transformed into 
$$\int_0^1 \frac{2du}{(1 + u^2} \frac{1}{\left(2 - \frac{1-u^2}{1+u^2}\right)}
=2 \int_0^1\frac{du}{3u^2 + 1} = \frac{2}{3} \int_0^1 \frac{du}{u^2 + 1/3}$$
can you continue now?

Comment: Okay but how am I supposed to get cos t = (1-u^2)/(1+u^2) from u = tan(t/2) ?  That's where I'm completely lost.

Comment: @Brandon,  i will edit my post. show some of the steps.

Comment: I'm trying to follow along but I'm still not sure how the cos x gets transformed like that.  Perhaps I'm simply not familiar that substitution.  Other than that the rest of the equation makes sense.  How am I supposed to know what to put in the place of cos x?  Is it simply a well-known substitution?

Comment: @Brandon, here is way to see that. you need the half/double ante formula: $\cos x = \cos^2 x/2 - \sin x/2 = \frac{\cos^2 x/2 - \sin^2 x/2}{\cos^2 x/2 + \sin^2 x/2}$ now divide both numerator and denominator by $\cos^2 x/2.$ it gives you $\cos x = \frac{1 - \tan^2 x/2}{1 + \tan^2 x/2}$

Comment: Oh okay cool.  That makes a lot more sense.  I've actually never seen that formula before.

Answer (score 2):

We start with 
$$\int_0^{\pi/2} \dfrac{1}{2-\cos{x}} dx$$
Let's start as you suggest and see where it takes us, multiplying top and bottom by $2 + \cos x$.
$$ \int_0^{\pi/2} \frac{2 + \cos x}{4 - \cos^2 x} dx = \int_0^{\pi/2} \frac{2 + \cos x}{3 + \sin^2 x} dx.$$
The mathematics of wishful thinking suggests that we split this integral and handle the easy part first.
$$ \int_0^{\pi/2} \frac{\cos x}{3 + \sin^2 x} dx = \int_0^1 \frac{1}{3 + u^2} du$$
when we perform the substitution $u = \sin x$. This is now a classic inverse trigonometric integral, and will lead you to $\arctan$.

What did we leave behind? We left
$$ \int_0^{\pi/2} \frac{2}{3 + \sin^2 x} dx.$$
This looks a bit tricky. One way to proceed is to recognize $3 = 3\sin^2 x + 3 \cos^2 x$, so that we have
$$ \int_0^{\pi/2} \frac{2}{3 \cos^2 x + 4\sin^2 x} dx.$$
Now multiplying by $\sec^2(x)/\sec^2(x)$ gives
$$\int_0^{\pi/2} \frac{2 \sec^2 x}{3 \cot^2 x + 4} dx.$$
Now you can finish with the substition $u = 3\cot^2 x + 4$.

Is this what I'd recommend? It's hard to say. The substitution you mention is a well-known substitution. But it's important to recognize that with these problems, as long as you follow your nose and charge forward, you'll probably reach a resolution.

Comment: $(2-\cos x)(2+\cos x)=4-\cos^2 x$, not $4+\cos^2 x$ - but then that _does_ equal $3+\sin^2 x$ so the rest goes through...

Comment: @StevenStadnicki oh, well what a silly mistake to start with

Comment: Apologies for the tone of my first post - I hadn't realized it was just a sign error there rather than a deeper error.  This is a nice approach all in all (+1), although I'd probably never find the final transformation myself.

Comment: Thanks for the alternate approach.  I just didn't go through with it enough when I tried it (and made some errors as well which didn't help).